# How to integrate Ember.js with Express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ember.js, integration

I haven't seen an up-to-date question like this one, so here we go.

How would I go about integrating an Ember.js frontend with an Express.js backend? I have an Express app exposing a RESTful API that I'd like to use Ember as a frontend for. Is there an example repo or something to help me get started?

Comment: That question is to broad, because it depends on how you defined the _interface_ of your server-side application. Normally you would use a RESTful interface for your server-side applications, because this is a common interface that is most likely supported.

Comment: @t.niese Assuming I'm only exposing a RESTful API from my Express app then.

Comment: As I don't know what you already have, you might take at first a look at [The Rest Adapter](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/models/the-rest-adapter/).

Comment: That makes sense. Do I just run `ember build` and include the generated files in my jade layout or something? I have no idea how to actually link the two together.

Comment: I cant help you with that. I only had a short look on ember and angular, so i don't have a in deep knowledge of them. But the techniques don't differ that much between different frameworks. I can't really recommend an article or tutorial, but maybe this one is ok [Ember Data: A Comprehensive Tutorial for the ember-data Library](http://www.toptal.com/emberjs/a-thorough-guide-to-ember-data) at least it looks complete on the first look. Anyway when asking a question on SO you already should have something we can work on. Such questions are way to broad.

Comment: Okay, so I've gotten it to integrate by building it with `ember build` and serving the `dist/` directory as a static directory from Express. That way I only need one command to run the entire thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: I thought you wanted to serve your app with your Express server. You just want to know how to use a rest api with Ember?

Definitely check out the RESTAdapter or JSONAPIAdapter

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api',
  host: 'https://express server here'
});
```

You should be able to serve the built version of your app with Express the way you normally would

```
ember build --environment=production
```

As @GJK pointed out, this isn't necessary for serving your app, but for a production build you would want to do this and serve out of the dist directory

I had an issue serving all of the routes and found this conversation helpful: [Rewrite rule](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/how-to-serve-all-routes-on-a-production-server-exactly/6372)

Unfortunately I dont have a repo to point you to but hopefully that helps

Comment: regarding the edit: Most likely, yeah. I'm completely new to Ember.

Comment: If you were willing to drop a few bucks on it, this book helped me a lot. https://leanpub.com/ember-cli-101

Comment: Express has nothing to do with the `ember build` command, which is from Ember CLI.

Comment: Right, but he would probably build it and serve out of dist. I was just including that step